# C++ 14 stl container queue

Tags: c++, c++14, std

what is difference between `queue<list<int>>` and `list<int> queue`?

I am confused between these two declarations.
In graph algorithms we use `list<int> queue`. So are these both same

Comment: Those two statements are not comparable. The first is a type and the other is a declaration. It looks like you have a `list` named `queue` which is unrelated to the type `queue`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::queue<std::list<int>>` is a type that is a `std::queue` of a `std::list` of integers.
`std::list<int> queue` is a variable named queue of the type `std::list<int>`

See preference for details on the difference between Types and Declarations:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations